# Move matched line with expr1 before another matched line with expr2 above in a file containing several expr2

Tags: awk, sed

I have a folder containing several files. In each of these files there might be one or more occurrences of the word `implicit`, and in some of the files with `implicit` there might be the sentence `use output` a few lines **after** `implicit`. In general I do not know how many lines separate them.
Some example files look like:

*ex1.f*

```
...some text...

implicit

...some other text...
```

*ex2.f*

```
...some text...

implicit
...a few lines...
use output

...some other text...
```

*ex3.f*

```
...some text...

implicit
...a few lines...
use output

...some other text...

implicit
...a few lines...
use output

...some more text...
```

*ex4.f*

```
...some text...

implicit

...some other text...

implicit
...few lines...
use output

...some more text...
```

I would like to move all occurrences of `use output` **above** the closest `implicit` that is found just before `use output`.

Note that in general the solution should be case insensitive.
Anything based on grep, sed, awk, is fine.

Conceptually, I think the solution should follow this logic:

1. match `use output`
2. delete that line and hold its content
3. reverse the search direction and look for the first occurrence of `implicit`
4. once matched, add the `use output` above the `implicit` line
5. reverse again the direction search and go back looking for `use output`

Comment: Replace all the `...`s and `some text`s with examples of actual values that could be in those locations so you don't get the solution to a problem you don't actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

range problems are simplified if we look at them in the reverse order. At the end just remember to reverse once again to maintain harmony in the Universe.

Using the range operator `,`
will max the regex count but increase readability.

```
tac file_name |
sed -e '
  /use output/,/implicit/!b
  /use output/{h;d;}
  /implicit/G
'   |   
tac ;
```

---

Without recourse to the range operator. Minimizes the regex count at the cost of code complexity.

```
tac  file |
sed -e '
  /use output/!b
  $q;h;N;s/.*\n//
  :loop
    n
  /implicit/!bloop
  G
'    |
tac  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the `tac` utility is not present, we can still do this within `sed`, but now we cannot print till we have seen the "use output" line, bcoz we don't know that another "implicit" line just might come before that.

```
sed -n '
  /implicit/!bp
  h
  :loop
    ${g;bp;} 
    n
    /implicit/{x;p;bloop;}
    H
  /use output/!bloop
  G;s/\n[^\n]*$//
  :p;p
' file
```